# Excel: Is this possible: Extract last line from within file linked in excel?

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way within excel to extract a line of text from a linked file in a cell?

Example: we are trying to track down the last user who used a computer, we have log files on a server for tracking user logins in a file. I was able to create a formula whick creates a link to the file.log for each computer, but now trying to figure out if i can extract the last line of text from that linked file into the excel cell.

i tried googling it, but only found how to extract from a cell of text.